# Not able to display data while Android watch Automation using Appium

Tags: appium, wear-os

I am trying to Automate Android wear application (Hotel locator app) available for both Android Watch and Mobile device. I have paired my device with watch emulator (adb -s  forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601). On watch emulator when I am clicking on Hotels option manually, it displays the nearby hotel data. However when I am trying to do the same through Appium script it is just showing the loading icon. 
I have invoked Appium server on ports 4723 for Android wear emulator and port 4724 for Android Physical Device.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the the source or a sample of what your hotel options source code is and what the appium source for the click is?

Comment: Sorry for tardy response. Please find the code at https://gist.github.com/MobilityTester/8830ee65a80aed1e6edd